# Can't identify this data structure / command doesn't work on structure

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures, split

I'm trying to split my data:

```
np.split(array, np.where(np.diff(array[:,1]))[0]+1)
```

My original dataset looks like this (it comes from an attribute table that was converted to a NumPy array by the TableToNumPyArray command):

```
[(1.0, 3.0, 1, 427338.4297000002, 4848489.4332)
(1.0, 3.0, 2, 427344.7937000003, 4848482.0692)
(1.0, 3.0, 3, 427346.4297000002, 4848472.7469) 
(1.0, 1.0, 7084, 427345.2709999997, 4848796.592)
(1.0, 1.0, 7085, 427352.9277999997, 4848790.9351)
(1.0, 1.0, 7086, 427359.16060000006, 4848787.4332)]
```

However, when I run the command: this error comes up:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

However, when I run the command on this dataset (same numbers, different format), it works:

```
 [[  1.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   4.27338430e+05
4.84848943e+06]
 [  1.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00   4.27344794e+05
4.84848207e+06]
 [  1.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+00   4.27346430e+05
4.84847275e+06]
 [  1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   7.08400000e+03   4.27345271e+05
4.84879659e+06]
 [  1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   7.08500000e+03   4.27352928e+05
4.84879094e+06]
 [  1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   7.08600000e+03   4.27359161e+05
4.84878743e+06]]
```

I don't know what the first data structure is, so I'm having trouble with conversion into a structure that works. Can anyone help me either convert the data or run the command on my original dataset? Thanks!

Comment: works fine for me using the input in your question

Comment: Does it work for the first dataset I provided or the second one? Because for me only the second one works.

Comment: The first works for me, as in the list of tuples converted to an np.array

Comment: My dataset is from an attribute table. I used TableToNumPyArray to turn it into a NumPy array - and then when I tried to split it, the too many indices error occurred. Do you know what might be causing the issue?

Comment: That is an arcgis function?

Comment: Yes - I'm working in the Python window of ArcGIS.

Comment: when you print the first data after `TableToNumPyArray` what does it look like and what is the shape?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85353/discussion-between-whent1991-and-padraic-cunningham).